# Where does tempdir() store data in R; possible to re-route?

Tags: r, performance, zip

My goal is to download shapefiles from the Census Bureau for the entire US. I've written a few functions that download the zip files from the Census website to a temporary directory (with some looping to get to every state), processes the files so that R can use them, and then dumps the rest. In theory I'd end up with one huge data frame that has the data I need. I'll write this to a .csv so I don't have to repeat the process later.

But! R keeps crashing after several states. I think the problem is how I temporarily store the data, but there could easily be more issues that make the code run super slowly and then freeze. It works perfectly if I only do one state.

This is where I get all the state numbers and the URLs of the download pages for each zip file.

```
mystates.us.unique = c("1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25","26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "53", "54", "55", "56")

mystates.us.url = ifelse(nchar(mystates.us.unique) == 1, paste("0", mystates.us.unique, sep = ""),
                         ifelse(nchar(mystates.us.unique == 2), mystates.us.unique, "HELPPPP"))
url = paste("http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/BG/2000/tl_2010_",
           mystates.us.url,"_bg00.zip", sep = "")
```

This is the function that makes the shapefiles usable.

```
process.shapefiles = function(folder, shapefile){
  block = readOGR(dsn = folder, layer = shapefile)
  block@data$id = rownames(block@data)
  block.points = fortify(block, region = "id")
  block.df = join(block.points, block@data, by = "id")
  block.df = subset(block.df, select = c(long, lat, group, BKGPIDFP00))
  names(block.df) = c("long", "lat", "group", "GEOID")
  block.df
}
```

Here is where I actually go to each website, download to the temp folders, process using the above function, and then put each state into it's respective entry in the list state.shapes

```
state.shapes = list(rep(data.frame(NULL), length(url)))
for(i in 1:length(url)){
    temp.dir = tempdir()
    temp.file = tempfile()
    download.file(url = url[i], destfile = temp.file)
    data = unzip(zipfile = temp.file, exdir = temp.dir)
    state.shapes[[i]] = process.shapefiles(temp.dir, strsplit(basename(url[i]), split = "\\.")[[1]][1])
    unlink(temp.dir)
    unlink(temp.file)
}
```

Any thoughts? 
Note: You'll need the packages rgdal, plyr, and utils

Comment: To see where your temporary directory is, run `tempdir()`. To get it to download somewhere else, change the variables `temp.dir` and `temp.file` to strings specifying whatever directory and file name you want.

Comment: which package is fortify in? how large is each stage.shapes, ie, how large is state.shapes getting after a few states? maybe you could take a step further and add a step to write to csv and then append the file at each iteration with a new state so that you dont keep growing an object in memory

Comment: tempdir() is in /var, but there's no path in front of it. I thought it was only part of R's memory.